# How to adjust the animation rate in a Manipulate environment

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d

The enclosed code is a simplified version of the "Make Your Own Solar System" demonstration.
How do I remove the manual Faster and Slower animation controls and add code for a
permanent very slow speed of rotation? Thank you for your help.

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{Hue[.12], {Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .1]},
   {FaceForm[], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .8 + .02]}, Gray,
   Table[Line[
     Table[{.8}[[i]] {Cos[ tt], Sin[ tt], 0}, {tt, 0, 2 Pi, 
       2 Pi/100.}]], {i, 1}],
   Blue, Sphere[.8 {Cos[ t], Sin[ t], 0}, .02]},
    PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, Boxed -> False, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, ViewAngle -> .340],
      "X1" -> {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 100, ImageSize -> Small}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The faster/slower controls can be controlled using `AppearanceElements`. The following values can be used in `Manipulate`:

> "StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton", "PlayPauseButton", "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"

Take the ones you want to use (you wanted to drop "FasterSlowerButtons"):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Hue[.12], {Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .1]}, {FaceForm[], 
    Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .8 + .02]}, Gray, 
   Table[Line[
     Table[{.8}[[i]] {Cos[tt], Sin[tt], 0}, {tt, 0, 2 Pi, 
       2 Pi/100.}]], {i, 1}], Blue, 
   Sphere[.8 {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, .02]}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> {400, 400}, Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  ViewAngle -> .340], {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 2 π, 
  AnimationRate -> .1, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton", 
    "PlayPauseButton", "DirectionButton"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The speed can be set with `AnimationRate`, as mentioned in David's answer.

Comment: My thanks to both Sjoerd and David for their help.

Answer (score 4):

Change the `AnimationRate` in the iterator:

```
Manipulate[ 
 Graphics3D[{Hue[.12], {Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .1]}, {FaceForm[], 
    Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .8 + .02]}, Gray, 
   Table[Line[
     Table[{.8}[[i]] {Cos[tt], Sin[tt], 0}, {tt, 0, 2 Pi, 
       2 Pi/100.}]], {i, 1}], Blue, 
   Sphere[.8 {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, .02]}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> {400, 400}, Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  ViewAngle -> .340],
 {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 2 \[Pi], AnimationRate -> .1, 
  ImageSize -> Small}]
```

Incidentally, for your repeated motion it is simplest to set the range (period) of your time variable to be 2 Pi.

Comment: A final suggestion to make your question and its answers more valuable to readers:  Title your question in the most specific and valuable way.  Your question really isn't about "rotation" (or even, more accurately "orbital rate") nor about "adding," but instead about controlling animation rate in a Manipulate environment.  A more helpful title might be:  "How to adjust the animation rate in a Manipulate environment" or something like that.  Such a title would help those whose Manipulate environments render linear motion, changes in color or size, or indeed any dynamic effect.